# Averaging v/s RMS

Tags: adc

Suppose we have a unipolar value being measured with an ADC,is there any advantage to using an RMS value as against a Average value of n samples ?
RMS is more computationally expensive,so would it make sense to do an RMS filtering in any specific case?

Comment: You mean averaging the samples to reduce noise or averaging "all" the signal to get its mean value?

Comment: Are you interested in the average *voltage* or the average *power*?

Comment: I am interested in averaging the samples to reduce noise.

Comment: I did not quite understand:"averaging "all" the signal to get the mean value",wouldnt it be the same as case 1,in case it is repeatedly done ?

Comment: This is just a "thinking out loud" kind of query :-)

Comment: What do you expect the average to _mean_? Is this a continuous signal or more of a oneshot sample?

Comment: For eg.say I want to use it as a feedback to control an output voltage ?

Comment: As I said its more of a hypothetical query.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a signal and you want to quantify it you have several options and these are the more common: -

- Average
- Peak
- Peak to peak
- RMS
- FFT

If you want to take the average of a signal it tells you exactly that - it's the mean of the samples. If you want to look for a peak or a peak to peak value that gives you maxima and minima. RMS tells you more about the signal's energy than either the above and FFT gives you RMS values for the various spectral components that make up the signal.

All these apply to unipolar and bipolar signals and they can be as different as chalk and cheese but it's down to what YOU want to do and what suits you.

Comment: Actually we were taking readings from a accelerometer,which was a bit noisy.So a prof. told us you might getter results if you take the rms of the readings,I was wondering what he meant.He went away before we could ask him more queries :-).

Comment: I think what you mean is take the RMS value of the voltage,if you want to do the FFT of a signal and take average values if you just want to smooth a signal of its noisy elements?

Comment: @EmbSysDev Without knowledge of the signal and, studying it and, understanding the application and, what you feel is important to measure I can't answer one way or the other. If something is noisy then filtering (analogue or digital) is my standard response. If you are interested in simple digital filters check out my website and find the pdf. It's only really suitable for EEs though.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically are interested in the RMS value, a filter is probably your best bet. Averaging a number of samples (equally weighted) for example, sampling at 1kHz, adding 100 samples, and outputting the result/100 at 10Hz can result in aliasing at a frequency lower than Nyquist (Fs/2) for the original sample rate of 1kHz (you may need an analog anti-aliasing filter for 5Hz rather than 500Hz.. because it is effectively being downsampled).

RMS will accentuate the noise and cause an offset from zero-average noise-- it's real if you're actually interested in power into a fixed resistance, for example, but for something like temperature it probably makes no sense.

Comment: *"Averaging a number of samples (equally weighted) can result in aliasing at a frequency lower than Nyquist (Fs/2)."* That's an odd statement. Can you explain exactly what you mean by it?

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks, it was a little unclear so I added an example that hopefully is helpful.

Comment: Ah, so it isn't the averaging *per se*, but rather the implied sub-sampling that causes the problem. When I think "averaging filter", I normally assume a sliding-window type of filter (a.k.a. "boxcar" FIR filter).

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes, exactly. Thanks for pointing out the ambiguous statement.

Answer (score 1):

RMS is Root Mean Square.

Root and square is mathematical method used to get absolute values.

In ADC measurements you can use average for unipolar signals.

For bipolar you can multiply negative ADC readings by -1 and avoid cpu intensive root calculations too.

Answer (score 0):

First let me quantify what you are asking with some notation.

The noise is the difference between the observed signal \$F(t)\$ and the true, but unknown real signal, call it \$u(t)\$.

We usually assume our observations are unbiased.  That is, if we could repeat the observation of the same signal over and over again and average it the results we could recover the original signal \$u(t)\$.  Mathematically, we write
$$E(F(t)) = u(t).$$

Now the problem is that we cannot observe all the possible \$F(t)\$. In fact, if \$u(t)\$ is not periodic we really only get to make one observation of our signal (but at many different values of \$t\$).

Just guessing from the problem given you probably want to consider a moving average:  That is, you want to estimate \$u(t_n)\$ via "averaging" the previous \$m+1\$ observed values \$F(t_n),....,F(t_{n-m})\$.

Now your question is to compare the quality of the averages
$$e_{avg} = \frac{1}{m+1}\sum_{i=0}^m F(t_{n-i})$$
and
$$e_{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{m+1}\sum_{i=0}^m F(t_{n-i})^2}.$$

Which estimate is better I will take to mean which ever one is most likely, on average, to be closer to \$u(t_n)\$.

Since this is getting a bit complicated maybe it is best to try a small example.  Consider the case when \$u(t) = 0\$ and the noise has independent standard normal distribution.  In this case \$e_{avg}\$ is \$N(0, \frac{1}{m+1})\$ and \$e_{rms}\$ is \$\chi_{m+1}\$.  So on average 
$$|e_{avg}-u(t_n)| = |e_{avg}| = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{(m+1)\sqrt{\pi}}$$ and

$$|e_{rms}-u(t_n)| = |e_{rms}| = m+1.$$

We can see in this example that \$e_{avg}\$ will provide a better estimate on average.

Now there are all sorts of noise that appear in signals. White noise from stochastic effects, normal noise from error, quantization noise from analogue to digital, etcetera and they will affect the probability distributions of \$e_{avg}\$ and \$e_{rms}\$.